# python curve_fit returns lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve-fitting, gaussian

The task is to fit some chunks (cand_peaks_xs) of data range (X and Y) with gaussian curve. The problem is that result is linear.

```
   for i in cand_peaks_xs:
                # approximate gauss
                x = X[i[0]:i[1]]
                y = Y[i[0]:i[1]]
                try:
                    mean = numpy.mean(x)
                    sigma = numpy.std(x)
                    param, cov = curve_fit(self.gauss, x, y, p0=[y.max(), mean, sigma])
                    self.ax1.plot(x, self.gauss(x, *param), c='r')
                except:
                    pass
```

[image: The result of work. Red lines are curves, built with the algorithm]
Red lines here are what I get with this program.

This is definition of gauss

```
def gauss(self, x, a, x0, sigma):
    return a*exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))
```

Comment: How have you defined `self.gauss`?

Comment: Also, as an aside, it looks like you're doing some kind of diffraction analysis. Possibly Rietveld refinement or such? You may be interested in http://www.diffpy.org/, it's a Python package designed for doing diffraction analysis (ignore me if my guess is wrong :P )

Comment: I've added the definition. What about your advice, I'll look, thanks

Comment: I'd suggest you print out the params you're getting and check they make sense (for example, is the peak position roughly correct?). I'd also suggest you make sure that your `self.gauss` equation works, try it with some known data and check it's working before you do any fitting. The advice about diffpy probably won't solve your issue, I just thought I'd mention it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def gauss(self, x, a, x0, sigma):
    return a*numpy.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))
```